# How can you put Admob banner at the bottom on both iPhone 4S and iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, admob

Prior to iPhone 5, i could place the admob banner at the bottom of the screen (just above the tab bar). But due to iPhone 5 screen size, everything is now disturbed. I even tried to do it through Autolayout (it didn't work). How can i do that for both screen sizes?

Here's my code -

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

        adMob = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                                367.0 -
                                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                                                GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

        adMob.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;

        // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
        adMob.adUnitID = @"XXXXXXXX";



        // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
        // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
        adMob.rootViewController = self;
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

        request.testing=YES;
        [self.view addSubview:adMob];

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
        [adMob loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
        [adMob release];

     // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
        // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.


    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

If you're using iOS 6 you should just use AutoLayout. You can put this code into your ad placement code after you add the banner into the view hierarchy:

```
self.googleAdBannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.googleAdBannerView];

// Constraint keeps ad at the bottom of the screen at all times.
[self.googleAdBannerView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

// Constraint keeps ad in the center of the screen at all times.
[self.googleAdBannerView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
```

Comment: +1 for autolayout. I found you also need to self.adBanner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; or else I got errors about conflicting constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `y` position based on which screen they are using.

Comment: If i change the Y position, the layout on iPhone 4 screen would be deteriorated which is an issue.

Comment: ... I mean, you move object frames using their `x` and `y`. You could make two different NIBs and load a different one based on the phone, I guess.

Comment: I'm using storyboard. And two different NIBs for two different devices doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: I agree. Which is why you should check which screen they are using and set the `y` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Auto Layout Property of View, there is no other way to solve because in any device height of view remain same which is now 499.0.

Comment: can you some more light on how to exactly use it for admob banner? I enabled it earlier but the view got disturbed. How can i disable it to change buttons layout?