# iOS iAd banner placement

Tags: cordova, ios6, iad

I would like to know what is the best practice and how to show an ad banner at the bottom of the screen. I am using phonegap 2.5 and I can get it to show on the top of the screen. This is how I am creating the adBannerView.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    adView = [[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    //adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 50); // if you want the banner to be on top of the screen remove this line
    adView.delegate = self;
    adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [theWebView addSubview:adView];

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

I am not sure if I'd want to fix the position based on the commented out line up above since  iphones (4,5) have different resolutions. Please let me know how I can place it in the bottom of the screen.

Thanks.

I tried what's in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200601/how-can-you-put-admob-banner-at-the-bottom-on-both-iphone-4s-and-iphone-5/13256266#13256266), but I get error regarding conflicting constraints

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
adView.frame = adFrame;
[theWebView addSubview:adView];
```

Comment: I finally added the banner in the xib file and used that property as an outlet. Somehow it's working in the portrait mode and at the bottom, can't make it work in landscape. But's it's good enough for me right now.